# karma.conf.js does not exist after upgrading to Angular 7

Tags: angular7

After upgrading to Angular 7 from Angular 5 ng test is not working it throws karma.conf.js does not exist!
I followed few other links it showed me to run npm run test or npm run test:watch but if I do that it exists out. Included that file in angular.json file even then I get the same issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thptq.png)